# Linear Gradient with multiple stops or multiple stroked lines in a HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

I'm currently rendering a background using around 600 stroked lines along the width of an image and then gaussian blurring them.

My problem is that this is proving to be relatively slow for a background and I'd prefer it if it was near instant.

I'm toying with the idea that a LinearGradient with multiple stops would be better for the job, What do you guys think would be better?

Comment: If your only metric is performance then benchmark both pieces of code and see which one performs best.

Comment: Ok will do! The real reason I asked was to find out if any one had already tested it, Thanks!

Comment: blur == evil performance eater.  Since gradients use blur to reduce banding, you're probably chosing between bad and worse. How about drawing your 600 lines + blur **once** and saving it to an image or offscreen canvas.  Then modify+apply the saved effect when needed.  That would get you a real performance boost.

Comment: Perfect idea! What's wrong with me!? I'd never even thought of doing it that way! Submit it as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by
markE

> blur == evil performance eater. Since gradients use blur to reduce banding, you're probably chosing between bad and worse. How about drawing your 600 lines + blur once and saving it to an image or offscreen canvas. Then modify+apply the saved effect when needed. That would get you a real performance boost